# How can I parse array JSON in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I did it easily in Android but Im little lost how to do it in iOs. 
My json is like:

```
[{"name":"qwe","whatever1":"asd","whatever2":"zxc"}, 
{"name":"fgh","whatever1":"asd","whatever2":"zxc"}]
```

If I do:

```
NSData *jsonData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];

rows  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

in rows can I access with?

```
NSString *name = [[rows objectAtIndex:0] [objectForKey:@s"name"]];
```

Or how I do that? thanks.

**FINALLY** `NSString *name = [[rows objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]];` WORKS! :D

Comment: what did happen when you tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that will work, however you want:

```
NSString *name = [[rows objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

(dropped extraneous square brackets and use `@"name"` as string literal).

However, is the input JSON really in UTF-32 format?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *row= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: jsonData options:        NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
        for (int i=0; i<[row count]; i++) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict=[row objectAtIndex:i];;
            NSString * name=[dict valueForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"%@",name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am quite sure, that `row`won`t be a NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `NSJSONSerialization` operation was successful, simply:

```
NSString *name = rows[0][@"name"];
```

`NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding` is suspicious, json data is more usually `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.